# Splitting string with delimiters in C - segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, string, split, char

I want to write a function that will split a string into a char array. I know that the result array will ALWAYS have only two elements - servername and serverport. I wrote this, but it gives me "Segmentation fault" after compilation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* splitString(char stringToSplit[])
{
    int i = 0;
    char serverinfo[2];
    char *tmp;
    tmp = strtok(stringToSplit, ":");
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        serverinfo[i] = tmp;
        tmp = strtok(NULL, ":");
        i++;
    }
    return serverinfo;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char st[] = "servername:1234";
    char *tab = splitString(st);

    printf("%s\n", tab[0]);
    printf("%s\n", tab[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: btw, `gdb` is useful for getting a gasp of where it's faults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char serverinfo[2];
```

allocates space for two `char`s, but you store `char*`s there, so make it

```
char* serverinfo[2];
```

But you return it from the function, however, the local variable doesn't exist anymore after the function returned, so you need to `malloc` it

```
char **serverinfo = malloc(2*sizeof *serverinfo);
```

and declare the function as

```
char **splitString(char stringToSplit[])
```

for the correct type.